# Can a shadow dancer's summoned shadow be polymorphed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, spells, polymorph

Let’s assume I'm playing a Shadow Dancer, epic level 70 or so. If I summon my shadow, can I polymorph it? If so, what are the limitations: can I polymorph it to be me and have a "doppelganger" of sorts? Would I still have control?

I had a fun idea of having a sort of “clone”, but one that acts as a completely commanded version under my control.

Comment: It seems like you're asking several different questions here... I'm going to edit out the 5e-related sections for now, and the question of conversion to 5e can be asked separately (it seems dependent on it working in 3.5e to begin with). That said, the multiple tags are confusing as well; is your original question about 3.5e, or Pathfinder?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! There are probably spells and magic items sufficient in *3.5* to enable *polymorph* to be used on a shadow, but I don't want anyone's research in that direction wasted if this is really a *Pathfinder* question. Please modify the question's tags appropriately. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: The rules for polymorphing in D&D 3.5e and Pathfinder are sufficiently different that I think we're going to need you to pick one or the other. What game are you actually playing?

Answer (score 3):

**No**

The description of *Polymorph* includes the following sections:

> Target:  Willing *living* creature touched
>
> Incorporeal or gaseous creatures are immune to being polymorphed...

The description of a Shadow in 3.5e (MM p221) categorises it as:

> Medium undead (incorporeal)

The *Polymorph* spell simply cannot target the Shadowdancer's summoned Shadow, because it is not a valid target.

This principle is extended to all Polymorph-type spells in the discussion of these on page 96 of PHB II:

> Incorporeal or gaseous creatures are immune to polymorph spells, as
>   are creatures of the plant type.

I suggest that polymorphing a shadow would be a sub-optimal strategy even if your GM house-ruled an exception.  If you want something that looks like a clone of you under your control then there are much easier ways - the *Seeming* spell could be cast on your Shadow, or polymorph a familiar, animal companion or hireling.

This answer addresses 3.5e rather than Pathfinder based on the title text of the question.